# UWP C#: Where does VS remember inheritance in a project

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, sealed

I was playing around trying to design a button and I came up with using a Border with a Button on it. Then I changed my MyClass to derive from Border. Border is a sealed class so the compiler flagged an error. So I removed the ": Border" from the class definition. Now however I still get a

Error   CS0509  'NumberedButton': cannot derive from sealed type 'Border'

As it's a partial class I wondered where else in the bowels of the project there is a memory of this? I've searched all the textfiles (I think) and come up empty-handed. See the snip on Imgur

[image]

Comment: I hate it so much when things like this happen!, I guess you've already tried all the usual tricks like reopening VS and doing a clean/rebuild?

Comment: The .g.cs may use boarder that it say you cant derive from it.Try clean it

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as usual, was newbie stupidity. The root object of the Xaml was still Border, whereas the code behind Class was NumberedButton.

I leave this here for others who may fall into the same trap.